# How can I constrain the GLM in R to fit the model between measured upper and lower values?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, constrained-regression

I have a data set for which the explanatory variable is being compared against two response variables, fairly standard. However, my task is to make the fit of the model be constrained between the upper and lower measurements of my explanatory variable.

Any advice, citations, code, anecdotes to help me search the net will all be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show some example data to give a feel for this, or at least give more details? What you're asking for might be impossible in general, depending on where the upper and lower measurements are located.

Comment: So, each row represents a geographical location, the columns of interest are, response var: temp and humidity. explanatory var: %mortality, but for the geographical location the test was ran multiple times, and has two other columns with the upper and lower mortality for the given locations. The task is to git the model of mortality against temp and humidity, whilst constraining the fit to the upper and lower mortality measurements.

Comment: In general, though, what if the upper and lower measurements are very close together - at [1,2] for one value of the temp, etc. and at [5,6] for the next higher value, then [1,2] again?  A general GLM won't fit the data at all with this constraint. You're bounds are likely weaker than this, but this means that any such constraint is unstable and there are cases where it could "break" the model.

Comment: The upper and lower measurements only exist for the explanatory variable if that makes a difference

Comment: You're mixing up "explanatory" and "response" -- I believe that mortality is your response (i.e. dependent) variable that you are trying to predict and that temperature and humidity are your explanatory (i.e. independent) variables. No, it doesn't make a difference if the upper/lower measurements are just for mortality; its hard to imagine how it could be different.

Comment: When you say you have upper and lower measurements, what precisely do you mean? Have you made two measurements for each set of values of the explanatory variables? Or have you made 2+ measurements for each set of values? Or do you have a continuous range of values for each set which you've simplified by picking the minimum and the maximum?

Comment: so I have many locations, for every location, multiple tests were carried out to assess mortality. My mortality % is an aggregate of all the test carried out in that one location. Accompanying this, are also the lowest and highest mortality percentage for that location.

Comment: With a GLM, the best thing to do (if possible and appropriate) would be to keep all the individual mortality measurements in the dataset being regressed, rather than computing the aggregates manually. This gives the GLM information on the variance of the mortality at that point. You can check after the fact if the result is bound between the highest and lowest measurements. It might be; it might not.